# SQL merge tables with matching columns

Tags: sql, left-join

How can I merge 2 tables with the same column names into 1 table? Something like this:

[image]

The 2nd table should fill in the 1st table.

This is as close as I got

```
SELECT * FROM
  Animals
LEFT JOIN Best
ON Animals.species=Best.species;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d0a98/3

But it seems to concatenate the 2nd table on there.

Is LEFT JOIN really the correct way to do this?

Comment: In 'Animals', the rat has the name Weston. In 'Best', the rat has the name Sandy. In your merged example, the rat has the name Sandy. What logic are you using to determine which name should stay?

Comment: Values in Best overwrite Animals except while null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should list the columns in the `SELECT`.  Then you would readily see that all you need is `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT a.price, a.species, COALESCE(b.name, a.name) as name
FROM Animals a LEFT JOIN
     Best b
     ON a.species = b.species;
```

Comment: Hi @gordon-linoff , is the left stil necessary with the `COALESCE`? I tried with an `INNER`and it does the trick. I bought your book 'data analysis using sql'

Comment: @AndyK . . . The `left join` ensures that you get all the rows from the first table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If my A table had many columns, is the only way really to list them all?

Comment: @KevinDuke . . . Yes, I think you would have to list them all.